# Angular confirmation alert not showing in modal

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, primeng

[Working Example of Success Message alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHCHl.png)

When clicking generate on the confirmation dialog modal the backend api is being called properly when the generate report button is clicked. However, the following message helper service alert as shown in the image above is not appearing. Could this be due to the dialog modal being open that is preventing the success message from showing?

[Dialog Modal with generate report button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmM5N.png)

HTML:

```
<p-dialog header="Confirmation Statement" [modal]="true" [visible]="display" [closable]="false"
  [style]="{width: '640px', minHeight: '480px'}">
  <ng-container>
    <div *ngIf="!generating">
      <p-radioButton name="period" value="asOfDate" label="As of Date:" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeriod"></p-radioButton>
      <p-calendar #asOfDateCal [(ngModel)]="asOfDate" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" [monthNavigator]="true"
        [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1900:2300" appendTo="body"></p-calendar>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p-radioButton name="period" value="timeframe" label="Reporting Timeframe:" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeriod">
      </p-radioButton>
      <p-calendar #beginDateCal [(ngModel)]="timeframeBegin" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" [monthNavigator]="true"
        [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1900:2300" appendTo="body"></p-calendar>
      <label>Thru</label>
      <p-calendar #endDateCal [(ngModel)]="timeframeEnd" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" [monthNavigator]="true"
        [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1900:2300" appendTo="body"></p-calendar>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Please select cost display format</label>
      <br>
      <p-radioButton name="costFormat" value="true" label="Monthly Cost" [(ngModel)]="monthlyIndictor"></p-radioButton>
      <br>
      <p-radioButton name="costFormat" value="false" label="Pay Period Cost" [(ngModel)]="monthlyIndictor">
      </p-radioButton>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="generating">
    <p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container>
    <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
      <button type=button pButton label="Generate" id="pplCvrgReptGenBtn" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="generate()"
        [disabled]="!valid() || generating ">
      </button>

      <button type=button pButton label="Close" id="pplCvrgReptGenClsBtn" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="hide()">
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</p-dialog>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.generateReport(`reports/sageReport/${this.erErId}/confirmation`, params, selectedPeopleId, null, this.monthlyIndictor)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.generating = false;
        this.messageHelperService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Request Submitted',
          detail: 'Requested Report is generating. You will be notified once complete'
        });
      }, errRes => {
        this.generating = false;
        this.messageHelperService.add({
          severity: 'error',
          summary: 'Error',
          detail: errRes.error.message
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: If you want to close the dialog, you should add `display=false` before make the `this.messageHelperService.add(...)`. The another option is change the "z-index" of the dialog using, e.g. `[baseZIndex]="1"`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably displayed below the dialog box so you do not see it
You can set the pop-ups to always be in the top layer by adding style = "z-index: 1000;" For confirmation alert